# iOS 16 Safari (and Chrome) not running iframe JS when type="module"

Tags: javascript, ios, module, safari

Everything is working flawlessly on desktop and Android Chrome and FF.

I can confirm that on the iphone iOS 16.1 I am using Safari `script` and `script type="module"` code and pages loaded from the same domain works on a very basic test site. However, when I use the following code:

```
var toto = document.createElement("p");
toto.innerHTML = "Hello world";
document.body.appendChild(toto);
```

In a `script` in an iframe on my main site (everything from the same domain via https), this code only works when the `script` is NOT `type="module"`. Without that it works, with that it appears to simply ignore it completely. I am at a loss - I could understand if there was some security setting I had that was blocking it but it works fine on the basic site. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this appears to be due to the iframe's content's `Content-Type`. As Chrome and FF show no difference in behaviour, I was only testing with a single situation where the iframe contents was `application/xhtml+xml`. On other examples, Safari was actually working fine. When I changed the content type from `application/xhtml+xml` to `text/html; charset=utf-8`, everything started working.

And of course, this [turns out to be documented](https://caniuse.com/?search=script%3A%20type%3A%20module)...

```
Module scripts do not load when the page is served as XHTML (application/xhtml+xml).
```

(only applies to Safari, others work fine)